# How to revert multiple impersonations?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, users, logins

When there are nested impersonations (as in `exec as user = 'user1'; exec as user = 'user2'; exec as user = 'user1';`), is there a way to revert all of them without having to use the `revert` command multiple times (e.g. `revert all;`)?

Or at least, if one must use `revert` repeatedly, is there a way to check if there is an active impersonation so one could loop the command as many times as needed (e.g. `while @@IMPERSONATION_COUNT > 0 revert;`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the name of the current user at the start of your batch, then compare that to the then-current user at the point where you want to `REVERT` back to the original user.

For instance:

```
DECLARE @Name SYSNAME;
SET @Name = SUSER_NAME();
SELECT @Name;
EXEC AS USER = 'SomeUser';
EXEC AS USER = 'SomeUser1';
EXEC AS USER = 'SomeUser2';
SELECT SUSER_NAME();
WHILE @Name <> SUSER_NAME() REVERT;
SELECT SUSER_NAME();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the current context to a cookie then revert to that cookie when you desire to.

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks! However, I don't like the idea of being stuck in an impersonation if I lose the cookie value for any reason. Seems like this feature is more useful to prevent revert than to allow reverting as many times as needed.